# RSA signed data verification not working PyCryptodome

Tags: python, rsa, signing, pycryptodome

Sorry for the very specific problem, but I am really going crazy here.
I am trying to make a module to simply import when I need to sign something or verify a signature but I encountered a problem, the verificator simply returns true wether I enter signed data or anything else,
here is the code:

RSA_Handler.py

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5
import pickle

def sign(data, exported_key):
    key = RSA.importKey(exported_key)
    signed_data = []
    signed_data.append(data)
    signed_data.append(PKCS1_v1_5.new(key).sign(SHA256.new(pickle.dumps(data))))
    return signed_data


def verify(signed_data, exported_key):
    data = signed_data[0]
    signature = signed_data[1]
    key = RSA.importKey(exported_key)
    h = SHA256.new(pickle.dumps(data))
    try:
        PKCS1_v1_5.new(key).verify(h, signature)
        return True

    except(ValueError, TypeError):
        return False
```

test01.py

```
from RSA_Handler import *
import pickle
import os


with open("keys.txt", "rb") as rb:
    keys = rb.read()




signed = sign("hello", keys)
trueorfalse = verify(["this will return"," true whatever I enter"], keys)

print(trueorfalse)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem (at least for the latest version of PyCryptodome, namely 3.9.8). It seems that the behavior depends on the padding type. In case of the module `PKCS1_v1_5`, which is currently used in the posted code, the verification does not raise a `ValueError` in case of an invalid signature, but returns the result as return value.

This means that your `verify()` function *always* returns `True`, because even in case of a mismatching signature neither a `ValueError` is raised nor the returned value is evaluated.

To solve the issue, your `verify()` function must be changed as follows:

```
def verify(signed_data, exported_key):
    data = signed_data[0]
    signature = signed_data[1]
    key = RSA.importKey(exported_key)
    h = SHA256.new(pickle.dumps(data))
    return PKCS1_v1_5.new(key).verify(h, signature)
```

which can be tested with:

```
# Signing
key = RSA.generate(1024)
keyPriv = key.exportKey()
signed = sign(b'Some data', keyPriv)

# Verifying
#signed[0] = b'Some data'             # Succeeds
signed[0] = b'Some other data'        # Fails
keyPub = key.publickey().exportKey()
verified = verify(signed, keyPub)
print(verified)
```

For PSS padding, i.e. for the module `pss` a `ValueError` is raised in case of an invalid signature. I.e. if you switch to this padding by replacing

```
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5
```

with

```
from Crypto.Signature import pss
```

and also `PKCS1_v1_5` with `pss` in the rest of the code, the logic in your `verify()` function can remain unchanged.

**EDIT:**

As explained in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63666465/9014097) from SquareRootOfTwentyThree, `PKCS1_v1_5` is an outdated module and instead the module `pkcs1_15` has to be used, which as expected generates a `ValueError` in case of an invalid signature, according to the documentation, [here](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/signature/pkcs1_v1_5.html#Crypto.Signature.pkcs1_15.PKCS115_SigScheme.verify).

Comment: This answer was accepted but it is not fully correct. The OP is just importing an old module (PKCS1_v1_5), and expecting it behaves like a different, newer one (pkcs1_15). The PyCryptodome documentation only uses the latter.

Comment: Yes. Using the `pkcs1_15` module is the correct way to fix the issue. I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing the obsolete module `PKCS1_v1_5`, which is not actually documented in in PyCryptodome. In your code, you must have instead:

```
from Crypto.Signature import import pkcs1_15
```

The PyCryptodome documentation (https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/src/signature/pkcs1_v1_5.html) shows examples of the right way to verify PKCS#1 v1.5 signatures.

The old module you are using (that is, `PKCS1_v1_5`) is there purely for backward compatibility with PyCrypto, where it behaves in the same way you are observing (i.e. without exceptions - which is not that great, the new module is better).